# Batch file adding 1 before executing command

Tags: batch-file, sed

I have a batch script which echos commands to separate batch files, and then calls those files. Whenever the external batch file commands are executed, a random 1 is added before the command. This wasn't happening before, and then seemingly randomly started occurring. It stops the SED command in the batch file from executing properly.

```
SED -n -e "/point1/,/point2/p" test.csv > point1.csv
```

is output as

```
SED -n -e "/point1/,/point2/p" test.csv 1>point1.csv
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, you are using Windows and so anything is possible for any/no reason. Just install cygwin and run your commands from a shell - save your sanity...

Comment: The redirection operator `>` is equivalent with `1>`; a redirection is echoed with the redirection handle (`1` in this case, meaning the standard output, _STDOUT_) added in case there is none provided explicitly; also `<` would become `0<`...

Answer (score 2):

The character immediately before the redirector is a logical device number. 0 is stdin (usually keyboard), 1 is stdout (usually console) 2 is stderr (usually also console).

The syntax ">filename" is in fact a shortform of "1>filename" hence the appearance of the "1".

Sadly, your description does not allow your problem to be duplicated. "the SED command in the batch file from executing properly" means "some SED command in some batch file (generator or subsidiary?) from executing as I expect (unspecified)"

Please provide examples of the generating command, the subsidiary batch generated, the data to be processed, the expected result and the actual result. (No need to go overboard - a few lines is all that's required - simply edit your question to include this data)

Comment: I solved the problem. It turned out to be unrelated to 1>. 

However, I am curious as to why windows started printing out the 1, when it did not do so before?

Comment: AFAIR, 'twas ever thus on NT, dating back to NT4 in 1996 or before. For compatibility reasons with DOS scripts, `1>` and `>` are synonymous. `2>` is not used as often; probably provision for complying with theory (error reports to stderr, normal output to stdout.) To see it in all its glory, try turning `echo` on and the commands will be displayed on-screen. The sticking point is `echo 12 x>file` which will for instance `echo` "12 " to the file if `x` is `1` or `echo` "12 " to the screen and create an empty file if `x` is for instance `3`.

Comment: The appearance of a single digit directly before a redirector invokes this behaviour - 0,1,2 are the only devices implemented, but any digit will seem to act oddly. Hence, the syntax `>filename echo 12 3` is usually implemented.